# Batch Normalization in a Custom Estimator in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm referring to a Note at [tf.layers.batch_normilization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization):

> **Note**: when training, the moving_mean and moving_variance need to be updated. By default the update ops are placed in tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, so they need to be added as a dependency to the train_op. For example:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

How would one implement this in a Custom Estimator?  For example looking at this example on Tensorflow's website: [The complete abalone model_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators#the_complete_abalone_model_fn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can pass the train_op you refer to the train_op parameter of the EstimatorSpec.

Answer (score 2):

On the following issue, at the very bottom you have an example
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16455

```
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    lr = 0.001
    optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=lr, decay=0.9)
    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                      loss=loss,
                                      train_op=train_op)
```